# RStudio Not Executing Markdown Code Chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I am working on an R markdown document for my homework assignments. I'm running into a problem with code chunks. The first chunk in my document runs properly, with the following code.

```
{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(zoo)
library(kableExtra)
data <- read_xlsx("C:/Users/***/Downloads/***.xlsx")
```

When I try to input the following code in a subsequent chunk, R Studio does not let me execute the cell.

```
{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
x <- data$Poverty
y <- data$Test
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? How do I get R Studio to run more than one code chunk?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious about this. Are there any warnings/errors? Are there any other code chunks between these two or before the first?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue several times.

The most common reason is that you have (probably) accidentally removed the

```` ``` ```` three backticks which demarkate the end of a code chunk.

````
```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)  
library(readxl)  
library(zoo)  
library(kableExtra)  
data <- read_xlsx("C:/Users/***/Downloads/***.xlsx")
```
````

Hopefully this solves your problem!